# FlowAccumulation working when run as geoprocessing tool but not in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, hydrology

I have a problem with this code:

```
#actual problem code
flow_dir_rast = flow_dir
in_weight_raster = mine_flac_weight
data_type = "FLOAT"
flow_direction_type = "d*"

# run the flow accumulation tool using the above parameters
print ("running weighted flow accumulation.")
mine_flac = arcpy.sa.FlowAccumulation(flow_dir_rast, in_weight_raster, "FLOAT", "D8")
print ("weighted flow accumulation complete.")
```

I get this error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000858: ERROR 000367: Invalid GP data type. Mask is not a member of the environment's domain.
Failed to execute (FlowAccumulation).
```

It seems that when I run these parameters through ArcGIS Pro's flow accumulation tool itself, it seems to work.
this is the code that ArcGIS Pro gives me if i copy and paste

```
    out_accumulation_raster = arcpy.sa.FlowAccumulation(
    in_flow_direction_raster=r"C:\Users\ArcGis\Documents\Felix's Working Files\data\analysis\01_merg_HydroSheds\flow_dir",
    in_weight_raster="in_weight_raster",
    data_type="FLOAT",
    flow_direction_type="D8"
)
out_accumulation_raster.save(r"C:\Users\ArcGis\Documents\Felix's Working Files\ArcmapToArcPro\Test\Test.gdb\FlowAcc_flow6")
```

However when I copy that code from the history tab and then paste it to run. I get the same error.

What did I do wrong?

As far as I can tell. They are the same

This is the full length of code:

```
# import packages
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


############### User Defined Parameters ###############


### data inputs ###

# the HydroSheds flow direction raster created from running AB_merg_HydroSheds_a_flow_dir.py
flow_dir = "C:/Users/ARCGIS/Documents/Felix's Working Files/data/analysis/01_merg_HydroSheds/flow_dir"

# the reclasssified landcover raster created from running AC_reclassify_landcov.py 
mines = "C:/Users/ArcGis/Documents/Felix's Working Files/data/mining/DMTI_2021_CMCS_MiningAreaRegion/DMTI_2021_CMCS_MiningAreaRegion/data/geodatabase.gdb/DMTI_2021_CMCS_MiningAreaRegion"

# the path to the default flow accumulation raster. This is the raster that the will be used as the denominator when calculating weighted flow accumulation
# A defualt flow accumulation raster for Canada using the HydroSheds data is created from running AD_Canada_flow_acc.py
default_flow_acc = "C:/Users/ArcGis/Documents/Felix's Working Files/data/analysis/03_Canada_flow_accumulation/dflt_flow_acc"

# path to the stream network
stream_network = "C:/Users/ArcGis/Documents/Felix's Working Files/data/analysis/03_Canada_flow_accumulation/streamNetwork"

# a folder to store intermediate files created while running the script along the way of getting to the final output
intermediates_folder = "C:/Users/ARCGIS/Documents/Felix's Working Files/data/analysis/05_mining_flow_acc/intermediates"
intermediates_folder_name = "intermediates"

# the folder where the output percent of land use upstream rasters will be created. A raster will be created and saved here for
# each land cover category present in the landcov raster file specified above 
output_folder = "C:/Users/ARCGIS/Documents/Felix's Working Files/data/analysis/05_mining_flow_acc/outputs"
output_folder_path = "C:/Users/ARCGIS/Documents/Felix's Working Files/data/analysis/"
output_generalfolder_name = "05_mining_flow_acc"
output_folder_name = "outputs"
# the name of the output raster
output_name = "mine_pflac"


############### The Code ###############
# Checking if out folders exist and if not Creating output folders. 
# Checking if intermediates folder exist and if not creating intermediates folder.
print("Checking for output_folder")
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name):
        arcpy.management.CreateFolder(output_folder_path, output_generalfolder_name)
        print (output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name + " created")
        arcpy.management.CreateFolder(output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name, output_folder_name)
        print(output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name+ "/" + output_folder_name + " created")
    else:
        print (output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name + " already exists")
        arcpy.management.CreateFolder(output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name, output_folder_name)
        print (output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name+ "/" + output_folder_name + " created")
    # Checking if intermediates folder exist and if not creating intermediates folder.
    if not os.path.exists(intermediates_folder):
        arcpy.management.CreateFolder(output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name, intermediates_folder_name)
        arcpy.management.CreateFolder(intermediates_folder,"recls_lndcov")
        print (intermediates_folder + "/" + "recls_lndcov created")
    else:
        print ("folder already exists")
else: 
    print("folder already exists")
    print (output_folder_path + "/" + output_generalfolder_name + "/" + output_folder_name)

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

### Geoprocessing Settings ###
arcpy.env.snapRaster = flow_dir
arcpy.env.cellSize = flow_dir
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


### project mine data to match hydrosheds projection system

# create output name of the projected feature class

mines_prj = os.path.join(intermediates_folder, "mines_prj.shp")


# check if the data set exixsts
if not os.path.exists(mines_prj):
    # if it doesn't exist create the dataset

    # project tool parameters
    in_dataset= mines
    out_dataset = mines_prj
    out_coor_system = arcpy.Describe(flow_dir).spatialReference
    transform_method = "#"
    in_coor_system = "#"
    preserve_shape = "#"
    max_deviation = "#"

    # run the project tool using the above parameters
    arcpy.Project_management (in_dataset, out_dataset, out_coor_system, transform_method, in_coor_system, preserve_shape, max_deviation)

print ("mine data has been projected.")


### convert mine data from polygon to raster for use as a weight in flow accumulation

# create output name of polygon to raster conversion
mine_rast = os.path.join(intermediates_folder, "mine_rast")


# check if the output dataset exists,
if not os.path.exists(mine_rast):
    # if the dataset does not exist, create it
    
    # polygon to raster parameters
    in_features = mines_prj
    value_field = "FID"
    mine_rast = mine_rast
    cell_assignment = "#"
    priority_field = "#"
    cellsize =  arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(flow_dir, "CELLSIZEX") # gets the x dimension of the cell size from the flow direction raster 

    # set environmental settings for the polygon to raster tool 
    arcpy.env.snapRaster = flow_dir   # sets the HydroSheds flow direction raster as the snap raster
    arcpy.env.extent = flow_dir  # sets the HydroSheds flow direction raster clipped to the study boundary as the processing extent


    # run the polygon to raster tool using the above parameters
    print ("Coverting mine area polygons into raster format for use as weight in flow accumulation.")
    arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion (in_features, value_field, mine_rast, cell_assignment, priority_field, cellsize)

print ("mine area raster created.")


### convert mine raster to a binary raster for use a weight raster in flow accumulation

# create name for mine area weight raster
mine_flac_weight = os.path.join(intermediates_folder, "mine_flacw.tif")

# check if the output dataset exists,
if not os.path.exists(mine_flac_weight):
    # if not create the dataset using the con tool
    # Con tool parameters
    in_conditional_rast = IsNull(mine_rast)
    in_true_constant = 0                    # areas where the raster has no data values will converted to 0 
    in_false_constant = 1                   # areas where the raster is not no data (i.e., the areas where the raster has values) will be converted to 1
    where_clause = "#"

    # run the con tool with the above parameters
    print ("Converting mine area raster to binary weight.")
    mine_flac_weight = Con(in_conditional_rast, in_true_constant, in_false_constant, where_clause)
    # save the output dataset
    mine_flac_weight.save(os.path.join(intermediates_folder, "mine_flacw.tif")) # saves the binary raster 
    print ("Binary mine area weight raster created.")


### run flow accumulation with the mine area weight created above

# flow accumulation parameters
flow_dir_rast = flow_dir
in_weight_raster = "#"
#mine_flac_weight

data_type = "FLOAT"
flow_direction_type = "d8"

# run the flow accumulation tool using the above parameters
print ("running weighted flow accumulation.")
mine_flac = arcpy.sa.FlowAccumulation(flow_dir, in_weight_raster, "FLOAT", "D8")
print ("weighted flow accumulation complete.")

#save the output dataset
mine_flac.save(os.path.join(intermediates_folder, "mine_flac")) # save the output

### percent mine area flow Accumulation ###
arcpy.env.mask = stream_network # set the mask to only consider areas on the stream network

print ("Calculating the percent of upstream area affected by mining.")
# calculate the percent of upstream area affected by mining
mine_percent_flac = mine_flac/Raster(default_flow_acc)*100

# save the output to the output folder
mine_percent_flac.save(os.path.join(output_folder, output_name))

print ("Percent of upstream area affected by mining calculated.")

DoneMessage = "\nDone :)"
print (DoneMessage)
# done
```

Comment: You need a comma between *"FLOAT" "D8"*, also check the environment variable in your geoprocessing options and make sure it's valid.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have added the comma between "FLOAT" and "D8" but it seems that I Still get the same error. When I run the flow accumulation tool with the same parameters, it runs, but when the arcpy code is copied and ran, I get the same error.

Comment: It's bad practise to have  apostrophes and spaces in folder paths, so "Felix's Working Files" will undoubtedly unhinge python. I would correct that for a start. Also the error makes reference to Mask are you showing the full code? Because we are not seeing where you set this?

Comment: @Hornbydd I didnt show the full code. I wasnt sure if I would be able to because the script itself is quite large. the mask refers to me using env.mask to a stream network file that i created in another script.

Comment: Well if you are not show the full code then don't expect anyone to answer this as no one has the time to second guess every possible issue.

Comment: The key here is to make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your existing code that provides all the unknowns, so the folks who want to help don't get caught up in a round or two of "This doesn't look right"/"It's not really like that" (which tends to eat into the intrinsic helpfulness compulsion in even the most dedicated SE participants).

Comment: @Vince Totally fair. I just was not sure if it would be feasible since its almost 200 lines of code.